# Compute time in Google Sheets given m/s suffix

Tags: google-sheets

I have a time in this format `3m24.3s`. I need to get Google Sheets to recognize this as a duration, not a time (i.e. not 12:03:24 AM)

I am trying to use a custom time/date format but I keep getting `#ERROR` in the cell

[image]